# `case` doesn't switch correctly with strings

Tags: common-lisp, conditionals

I have the following code which doesn't work:

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl)) 
(setq mymachine (system-name))
(case mymachine
  ("HP" (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/hp")))
  ("DELL" (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/dell")))
  ("MBP.local" (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/mbp")))
)
```

There's something happening in the key comparison between the variable `mymachine` and its three possible values. The following does work, however:

```el
(when (string= system-name "HP")
  (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/hp")))
(when (string= system-name "DELL")
  (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/dell")))
(when (string= system-name "MBP.local")
  (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/mbp")))
```

But I would prefer, for the sake of legibility, to use the `case` key selection.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cl-case` uses `eql` for comparisons, so string get tested for identity not for equality in the sense of `string=`. You can fix this by just switching to `pcase` (or, if you really want to use `case`, convert to symbols instead: match `(intern mymachine)` against `'HP`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain me the difference between `case` and `pcase` (the info I've found is a bit technical for me)?

Comment: `case` uses `eql` to test equality, whereas `pcase` will use a variety of different predicates, depending on the data. When a pattern is a string, `pcase` tests with `equal`. As well as the respective docstrings, also see `C-h i g (cl) Conditionals` and `(elisp) Pattern matching case statement`. Note that `pcase` provides rather flexible pattern-matching functionality; it's not simply a `case` alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Your second version would more typically be written as a `cond` form:

```el
(cond ((string= system-name "HP")
       (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/hp")))
      ((string= system-name "DELL")
       (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/dell")))
      ((string= system-name "MBP.local")
       (setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "packages/mbp"))))
```